# On principal non-maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain but $R$ is not a field. Prove that, in $R[x]$, $\langle x\rangle$ is maximal principal ideal (that is, maximal among principal ideals) but not a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R$ is not a field, there is nonunit element $a\in R$. Consider the ideal
$$
\langle a,x\rangle =\{ra+sx:r,s\in R[x]\}.
$$

---

**Add.** To prove $(x)\subsetneq(a,x)$, check $a\notin (x)$.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me? Please

Comment: @chuyenvien94: Show that tetori’s idea is a proper ideal that properly contains $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: But why $<x>$ is maximal principal ideal (that is, maximal among principal ideals)

Comment: @chuyenvien94 if $(x)\subset (r)$ then $r\mid x$. It forces $r=1$ or $r=x$.

Comment: I need more details to prove tetori’s idea is a proper ideal that properly contains  $<x>$. Help me, please.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 you want a detail of a proof of $(x)\subsetneq (a,x)$?

Comment: Yes I want it. Help me

Comment: @chuyenvien94 I write how to prove it in my post. More precisely, $a\notin (x)$ iff $x\nmid a$. It is trivial that $x\nmid a$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood.